# C#: Object cannot be cast from DbNull to other types

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oracle, datatable

I have read several posts on this online, but none of them have resolved my issue.
Most of the questions posted online point me towards checking Dbnull values from the database and I am doing that in the code.

Here's the code where the exception is thrown:

```
int rowNum = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[r][dataTable.Columns.Count - 2]);
```

Here's the code where I am checking for the dbnull values:

```
for (int r = 0; r < dataTable.Rows.Count - 1; r++) //rows
{
    for (int c = 1; c < dataTable.Columns.Count - 2; c++)
    {
        object val = dataTable.Rows[r][c];
        if (!val.Equals(DBNull.Value))
        {
            haveValues = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am reading the values from the excel spreadsheet.

Please point me in the right direction. 
Thanks in advance.

Dimpy

Comment: Where is the code that belongs to your exception? I only see two different lines of code that do not apply each other. Can you show where you call the line that causes the error?

Comment: have you tried to use val != DbNull.Value instead of !val.Equals(DBNull.Value)?

Comment: You're checking if there's *at least one* value in the result set. That's inverted - you can only read values if they are not `DBNull`. So if you don't want to do field-by-field checks, you need to invert your logic - if there's at least one value that's `DBNull.Value`, you can't read the data.

Comment: I finally did not find a solution to the problem. The same code works fine for my colleagues working on the same project. It must be a dll discrepancy, may be. I have a newer version of telerik and syncfusion dlls which we are currently using and that might be an issue too. Not sure, but I did not want to spend any more time on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check for DbNull **before** calling Convert.ToInt32: as you have seen, this will raise an exception if the value is DbNull.
something like:

```
object x = *value from db*
int y;
if (x != DbNull.Value)
    y= Convert.ToInt32(x);
else
    //handle null somehow
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check:

```
dataTable.Rows[r].IsNull(c)
```

`c` can be the index, the column name or the DataColumn

Answer (score 0):

for (int c = 1; **c < dataTable.Columns.Count - 2**; c++)

You don't check for count-2 so
dataTable.Rows[r][**dataTable.Columns.Count - 2**]
could be DBNull and your Convert fails

Comment: Now to think of it, He might be outside his data. looking for row -2 and -1 where they start from 0

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do if(varFromSQL.ToString()!="") and then carry on with my business. Works like a charm every time.
And then if i need to System.Convert.ToSomething() i can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this: DBNull.Value.Equals(dataTable.Rows[r][c]) if you want the index of the column you can use row[dataTable.Columns.IndexOf(col)] inside the foreach.

```
for (int r = 0; r < dataTable.Rows.Count - 1; r++) //rows
        {

            foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Rows[r].Table.Columns)
            {
                if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(dataTable.Rows[r][col.ColumnName]))
                {
                    haveValues = true;

                }
            }
```

And Please provide more information about the type of exception, maybe the error is accessing an invalid index => int rowNum = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[r][dataTable.Columns.Count - 2]); Why you use ...Columns.Count - 2 ?, What about if the count of columns is equals to 1 ?

I Hope to this helps.

Regards

Comment: I used count-2 as there is a hidden field within the excel spreadsheet and in my case I can upload it to the grid only when I un-hide the column. Specifically error is : An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: The exception is thrown specifically on int rowNum = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[r][dataTable.Columns.Count - 2]); It has 12 columns; the last one being a hidden column, it says it cannot recognize the last column. Works fine when it is unhidden. Any idea on dealing with hidden columns?

Comment: user3114594, i have an application using something like this: if(!DBNull.Value.Equals(dataTable.Rows[r][col.ColumnName])) but it is a web application with sql server, for excel maybe you shuld check the amount of columns and then validate or maybe ask if the column name exists => xRow.Table.Columns.Contains("name_of_column")